# orderByChild().equalTo() Firebase complexity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to know how fast orderByChild().equalTo() process works (for Java), and tricks to make it faster.

Since I use this a lot in my application.

Help me, please.

Comment: It works very fast. Doesn't that happen in your case as well?

Comment: It works well, but I would like to know if I have 1e6 items in the database and 1e6 queries, it will work quickly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have 16 items in the database and you want to perform a query for each one of them?

Comment: I has the function for checking is user exists, and i want to know how fast would it work(for one request) if i have 1000000 users in database.

Comment: Which database are you using, Cloud Firestore or the Realtime Database?

Comment: Realtime database

Comment: The number of users "isn't relevant" - it will be almost instantaneous. More importantly `.orderByChild` will have nothing to do with seeing if a document exists, so it's not clear why that's in the question.

Answer (score 1):

According to:

> I am interesting how fast orderByChild().equalTo() process works(for java), and tricks to make it faster.

And your comment:

> I have the function for checking if a user exists, and I want to know how fast would it work(for one request) if I have 1.000.000 users in the database.

If you want to check if a user exists in the node that contains 1 MILLION users, in a schema that looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- users
       |
       --- $uid
            |
            --- //user data
```

Using the following code in Java:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid);
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            if(snapshot.exists()) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Users already exists");
            } {
                Log.d("TAG", "Users doesn't exist");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

It will work pretty fast.

However, according to the official documentation regarding how to [Scale with Multiple Databases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding):

> The best way to optimize performance and scale your data in Firebase Realtime Database is to **split your data across multiple Realtime Database instances**, also known as database sharding. Sharding gives you the flexibility to scale beyond the limits that apply to individual database instances, in addition to load balancing and performance optimization.

But this technique is recommended to be used only if you're using Realtime Database and you fit into any of the following scenarios:

> - You want to scale beyond the limit of 200,000 simultaneous connections, 1,000 write operations/second or any of the other limits for a single database instance.
> - You have multiple, discrete data sets and want to optimize performance (for example, a chat app that serves separate, independent groups of users).
> - You want to balance load across multiple databases to improve uptime and reduce the risk of overloading a single database instance.